# How to make an external api call outside of a container on ECS Fargate deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have read other questions about this that all mention enabling service discovery, but my issue is a little different as to how to go about setting this up for my current Fargate deployments.

I have four spring boot api containers built via Gradle, pushed to ECR, and deployed in ECS Fargate with Terraform IaC setting up the appropriate resources. Three of these containerized apis have environment variables set within them to reference the fourth container, thus making an external api call outside of the container to that one service. DNS and 443 load balancer is setup for these deployments.

I have created a new service in the cluster containing the api that needs to be discovered. I have enabled service discover and created a local CloudMap A record for the api and then set each environment variable in the other containzers to use that local A record url, e.g., ecsservicename.local. Additionally I have tried to dig the service that I am connecting to in the other apis and that returns an IP so I am sure that that is working.

My questions are as follows:

(1) Since really only one services should be picked up by the others, was it correct to set service discovery on that one api and not the others or should I set up service discovery on all the other apis?

(2) Even if route53 is setup should this be an A record or SRV? I was confused by the documentation as to when to use which on aws.

(3) Is there a better or easier approach to use for inter-container communication that I am missing?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear about your questions?

Comment: Yes that seemed to work. I only needed to set service discovery in that one api and then reference that service name in the container vars of the other apis. That said I originally configured this with a 443 load balancer which also has authentication and certs installed so that was a little tricky. Had to do some more configuration so I wouldn’t get hit with firewall but this works.

Comment: Tried to upvote but it said I needed 15 reputations points so I guess my account needs some more points :)

Comment: I accepted. In my coding context for security reasons we have to request permissions for new host names and can’t create subdomains at will. The easiest way to make a container externally accessible, though, aside from enabling service discovery is to create a host name for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. That's correct. Discovery should be set only for the **one service**. Other discoveries are not needed, as you are not inter-connection to those other services.
2. SRV also gives port, so from [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html):

> if the task definition that your service task specifies uses the **bridge or host network mode**, an SRV record is the only supported DNS record type.

3. I think your architecture is well thought and can't think of anything "easier" or better.